# filter an array from class

Tags: json, swift, filter

I tried to filter my class array but I keep getting an error and I have no idea why

this is my code :

```
var shops = [Shops]()
```

and the when I get data from server and save them

```
 let desgin = subJson["desgin"].stringValue

 let familiy_id = subJson["id"].stringValue


 var info = Shops(shopname: shopName, Logo: logoString, family_id: familiy_id , design : desgin )

self.shops.append(info)
```

> value of tuple string json has no member design

I'm trying to filter the shops with design. 
`Shops` is where I save the data coming as JSON

```
class Shop {
    ...
 var design: String?
    ...
}
```

Comment: can you show your json? does it have member `design`?

Comment: check my code again

Comment: @leo0019 where is Shops declared?

Comment: I think problem is this line  `Shops(shopname: shopName, Logo: logoString, family_id: familiy_id , design : desgin )` here you are using `Shops` but your class name is `Shop`

Comment: I declare shops before getting data

Comment: check my question again please

Comment: What is the difference between `Shop` and `Shops` ?

Comment: Shops is the class and shop is the variable

Comment: Please show the code for `Shops` and `Shop` both

Comment: it's shown in my question

Comment: You have only shown the code for class `Shop` but not for `Shops`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think problem is this line

```
 var shops = [Shops]()
```

and this line

```
 Shops(shopname: shopName, Logo: logoString, family_id: familiy_id , design : desgin )
```

You are using `Shops` to make an object and you are filtering according to `Shop` class

Your code should be this:

```
var shops = [Shop]()


 let desgin = subJson["desgin"].stringValue

 let familiy_id = subJson["id"].stringValue


 var info = Shop(shopname: shopName, Logo: logoString, family_id: familiy_id , design : desgin )

self.shops.append(info)

let filteredArr = self.shops.filter { $0.design != nil }
```

here is your class `Shop`

```
class Shop {
    ...
 var design: String?
    ...
}
```

Comment: perfect answer!!